# Scrape from website with all same span name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

is it possible to scrape “likes number” and “post number” from [this](https://onlyfans.com/elettra_pink) website and import data on google sheet?

Because when i try i get empty data since the span of those data are basically all the same…
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
As you even want to push that data to google sheet and read by back from their I could come up with the below solution you could modify according to your need.

First you need to install gspread library and follow this tutorial https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html to get the credentials to access the google sheets via api and then follow the below updated code.

Your sheet should be like this:

[image: gsheetsbefore]

Code:

```
import requests
import gspread

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'app-token': '33d57ade8c02dbc5a333db99ff9ae26a'}
gc = gspread.service_account(filename="credentials.json")
sh = gc.open("data")
for rownumber,rowvalues in enumerate(sh.sheet1.get_all_values(),1):
    if len(rowvalues)==2:
        if rowvalues[1]=='':
            cookies = requests.post("https://onlyfans.com/api2/v2/init", headers=headers)
            data = requests.get(f"https://onlyfans.com/api2/v2/users/{rowvalues[0]}", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
            if data.status_code == 200:
                data = data.json()
                sh.sheet1.update_cell(rownumber, 2, data["postsCount"])
        else:
            print(f"Check : {rowvalues}")
    else:
        cookies = requests.post("https://onlyfans.com/api2/v2/init", headers=headers)
        data = requests.get(f"https://onlyfans.com/api2/v2/users/{rowvalues[0]}", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
        if data.status_code == 200:
            data = data.json()
            sh.sheet1.update_cell(rownumber, 2, data["postsCount"])
    print(f"{rownumber} Processed")
```

Once you run this code you see will data has been updated in google sheets but before running this script follow the URL provided or else you will end up having errors.

Updated Gsheets:

[image: updatedgsheet]

Old:
Seeing to the network logs of that website I was able to extract your desired data by requests library and some of their API calls you check the `data.json()` dictionary for other data if required.
Follow the below code.

```
import requests
headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'app-token': '33d57ade8c02dbc5a333db99ff9ae26a'}
cookies=requests.post("https://onlyfans.com/api2/v2/init",headers=headers)
data=requests.get("https://onlyfans.com/api2/v2/users/elettra_pink",headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
if data.status_code==200:
    data=data.json()
    print(f'Posts:{data["postsCount"]}\nPhotosCount:{data["photosCount"]}\nVideosCount:{data["videosCount"]}\nFavoritedCount:{data["favoritedCount"]}\nSubscribersCount:{data["subscribersCount"]}')
```

Output:

[image: output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: is exactly what i was searching for but…how to “integrate” this in a google sheet? i mean, let’s say that i have the profile target link in A1, how can i have posts number in A2? Thank you in advance, very kind!

Comment: I have modified the answer you could check it and change it if required by following the `gspread` library.